# How to remove exception "not-null property references a null or transient value" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

I'm a beginner in Spring Boot and still in learning phase.

Here, I created an API to create an employee and save the information in database.

Here are the code for different layers.

### EmployeeContoller class

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;
import net.javaguides.springboot.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {
    
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        super();
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    
    // build create employee Rest API
    
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(employeeService.saveEmployee(employee), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

### Employee Class

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name",nullable=false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
}
```

### EmployeeRepository interface

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long >{

}
```

### employeeService Interface

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.service;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeService {

    Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee);
}
```

### EmployeeServiceImpl class

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.service.impl;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;
import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import net.javaguides.springboot.service.EmployeeService;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{
    
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    // Constructor based injection in case of mandatory parameters 
    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        super();
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }
    

    @Override
    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

}
```

I tried googling for the exception, but I was not able to figure out the issue

Please help..

Attached are the project tree and table structure
[Project Hierarchy]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp3Or.png)

[Table "employee"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z1Pp.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you try to call the saveEmployee api (with example request body)? The exception indicates that your request doesn't have the firstName field, which is marked as required in the Column annotation.

Comment: URL: http://localhost:8080/api/employees (POST method), sending a request via Postman.    {
    "firstName": "Indressh",
    "lastName": "Gupta",
    "email": "indreshk81@gmaail.com"
}

Comment: Looks fine to me, I've copied your source code into my example project, and it works. I suggest you to try to debug your code in the controller or in the service layer to determine the Employee entity has any data before saving.